# Get all The index of Any Word in the String

Tags: c#

I have one String , Which contain Word    more Than one time ..
I want to find Each occurrence of that word one by one  and need To add some other word after That ..

Example -

```
<start>
<child1>
.
.
.
<start>
<child2>
..
```

and So On ..

i tried .

```
int count = Regex.Matches(StrRemoveWrongData, @"<start>").Count;
```

its giving me count , there is any thing where we can go to every occurrence one by one .
and add new word below that ..

Comment: Well did you check String `Replace` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your title, to get all the index;

```
 var indexList = Regex.Matches(StrRemoveWrongData, @"<start>").Cast<Match>()
                    .Select(m => m.Index)
                    .ToList();
```

If your replacement algorightm is more complex than a simple then string you can use the overload of Regex.Replace

```
int count = 1;
var newstr = Regex.Replace(StrRemoveWrongData, @"<start>", 
                       m => { 
                           //Do some work
                           return String.Format("<child{0}>",count++);
                       }
              );
```

Comment: if my child is string mychild = "<child>1</child>\n\r<child>2</child>\n\r<child>3</child>";

Comment: I am Trying Lke This  string childExtract = Regex.Match(mychild, @"(?s)<child>.*?</child>").ToString();
                                           //Do some work
                                      
   return String.Format(childExtract, count++);  but it alwys replcing first child

Comment: @Dilip Why do you use `Regex.Match`? What is `childExtract`? I can't understand what do you want to do?

Comment: i able to do.........  string[] childExtract = Regex.Matches(mychild, @"(?s)<child>.*?</child>").Cast<Match>()
                                               .Select(a => a.Value).ToArray();
                                          return String.Format(childExtract[count], count++);

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do: `StrRemoveWrongData = StrRemoveWrongData.Replace(@"<start>", newString);`

Comment: but my newstring  for every <start> is new ..  Example   For first occurrence of <start> new string is <child1>    then for Second <child2>